# Regex to match URL Path pattern

Tags: java, regex, lua

I have 2 URI Patterns with their regex:

```
1. "/api/orders/{id}/{version}"   ->      "^/api/orders/.+/.+$"
2. "/api/orders/{id}"             ->      "^/api/orders/.+$"
```

But with the above regex, String `/api/orders/123-blah$-789/v1` matches both the regex patterns 1 and 2.

What regex can I use so that the above string matches only pattern 1's regex and not 2?

**(The path may or may not be URL Encoded)**

Comment: Why is this tagged with lua?

Comment: I do not know lua, but In java (probably all other regexes) `.` matches any character... including a `/`, so any string matching 1. will also match 2.

Comment: I need to write this in either lua  or java so

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict both pattern by using a negated character class `[^/]+` matching 1+ characters excluding a forward slash.

For the first pattern you can use:

```
^/api/orders/[^/]+/[^/]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7UCKzL/1)

For the second pattern you can use

```
^/api/orders/[^/]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g3xreT/1)

Comment: What if there are escaped / in the URL

Comment: @JeraldBaker this regex would match anything that is not a slash after orders/. Including white spaces. It would match Strings that are not a proper URL

Comment: @JeraldBaker If you want to match escaped forward slashes and not match spaces you can write it like this https://regex101.com/r/5ceRK5/1 and https://regex101.com/r/genvHE/1

Answer (score -1):

This might seem a little hardcoded but gets the job done. 
And personally I prefer regex to be very specific.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^/api/orders/.+/.+$");
    Pattern q = Pattern.compile("^/api/orders/[^/]+$");
    
    System.out.println(p.matcher("/api/orders/123-456-789/v1").matches());
    System.out.println(q.matcher("/api/orders/123-456-789/v1").matches());

    System.out.println(p.matcher("/api/orders/123-456-789").matches());
    System.out.println(q.matcher("/api/orders/123-456-789").matches());
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but this is NOT what i'm looking for!

Comment: @JeraldBaker - does this help `^/api/orders/[^/]+$` ?